# draw view in context, what does it mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, draw, cgcontext

I've got the view presented like this:

```
_myController = [[MSCustomViewController alloc] init];
    _myController.doc = (AWDOC *)_currentDocumentViewController.activeFile.document;
    _myController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.7/3.3 saturation:0.2 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    [self.view insertSubview:_myController.view aboveSubview:_myController];
    CGSize size = [_myController.view sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    if(size.height < _myController.frame.size.height)
        size.height = _myController.frame.size.height;
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0., CGRectGetMinY(_currentDocumentViewController.view.bounds) + (CGRectGetHeight(_currentDocumentViewController.view.bounds) - size.height) / 2., size.width, size.height);
    _myController.view.frame = myFrame;
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(myFrame), CGRectGetMinY(myFrame), myButton.frame.size.width, CGRectGetHeight(myFrame));
    _myButton.frame = buttonFrame;
    [_myButton setTitle:@"<" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

What does mean "draw this view with context or Draw"?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more where are you getting this message?

Comment: well it's just a task

Comment: still unclear, is this the error message?

Comment: No it's not error. I just wonder if I can draw a view using some Draw(cgrect etc) or CGContext methods

Comment: You can draw a view using CGContext methods, to be clear about the "draw view in context" see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740543/in-ios-core-graphics-what-is-a-graphicscontext/23404741#23404741

Comment: @Bikram do I have to create for it another view, or I can just draw it inside my ViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add default UIView to your viewcontroller to hold the built-in views like UIButton,UIImageView,UILabel.You add as:

```
UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initwithFrame:CGRectMake(..)];
```

Now, to make the custom drawings in the UIView, you have to define your own view ( you do this by creating new class inheriting UIView). Let's say the class you made is StandardView class.
When you inherit the UIView, drawRect: is the default method which is called when you initialize this uiview in your view controller:

```
Standardview * stndView = [[Standardview alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300];
```

So, you can place all your drawing stuffs inside your drawRect: method. Normally you do drawing either using OpenGL/ES or CoreGraphics. And when using the coregraphics functions you specify the context for every function of coregraphics.And that context means your graphic destination.